# What was the most commercially-successful Soviet Union production outside the USSR?

Tags: box-office

Any information I can find is either about box office revenue inside the USSR, or vague numbers that are about general financial success. However, what I'm interested in is finding which Soviet movie made the most money *outside* the USSR.

Comment: It would be stunning if the answer was not Bondarchuk's War and Peace (1965-67).

Answer (score 2):

Difficult to say, as you have gathered from there not being enough information on that topic.

From various lists, and regarding the US Box Office figures, the following seems to be:

- Waterloo (1970) US$ 3.5m (Note, a Soviet-Italian co-production)
- Moscow Does Not Believe in Tears (1980) US$ 2.5m
- Dark Eyes (1987) US$ 2.2m
- Little Vera (1988) US$ 1.2m
- The Blue Bird (1976) US$ 0.8m

YMMV